# How does Steam recognize an authorized computer to access shared library?

Tags: windows-10, steam, authorization

My friend shared his library with me, and he had to log in to Steam on my machine and add the computer to the authorized list and then logged out.

Now every time I log in to my account on Steam I can see his games in my list.

The question is where does Steam store my computer's MAC (or encrypted key, or whatever) on my machine?

I'm planning to reinstall Windows and I wonder if I copied the Steam folder as is, along with the registry keys, would Steam would still recognize my computer? Or do I have to ask my friend to log in again and repeat the process?

Answer (score 0):

My experience with Steam is that all information is kept on their servers.
I believe that they do not depend on local storage, so copying their folder
is not useful. All you will need to do is login to Steam again after
reinstalling Windows and Steam.
You will still need to verify the login via email sent to your email
address.

You may examine the Steam folder at `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Steam`.
I did, and didn't find anything that looked like user information.

In fact, I once gave my Steam login to a friend, who logged-in to my account
on his computer and added a game. When I went into Steam on my computer,
the game was there.

Steam is made so your games are playable from every device on which you
login to Steam.
With the
[Steam Link service](https://store.steampowered.com/steamlink/about/)
you can now even stream and play your collection of games on a desktop or
phone device wherever you are.

From [Steam help](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8963-EIKC-3767#multiple):

> **Can I use my Steam account on other computers?**
>
> You may use your Steam account on any machine which can connect to the
>   Steam network - Steam allows you to download and install any games
>   registered to your account as soon as you log in.

So all you need is a good internet connection.

EDIT

Since it seems that your friend used the Steam feature of Family Sharing,
that kind of sharing is truly to a device and account.
Your friend will need to revoke your old device and authorize the new one.

Steam technology is very sophisticated, so I do not believe that by copying
a single folder you can authorize a device. As their entire technology
is based on the cloud, I'm quite sure that Family Sharing is also
handled this way.

Comment: Thanks for the info, that's not what I'm asking though, It is undisputed that all my account information are saved on their servers, and I only need to log in so they can recognize me, not the computer I'm logged in from.
In the case of a shared library, however, the giver has to authorize a specific computer, not a specific person, hence my question.
So if the giver authorizes my computer, I can't just log in to any other computer and still uses his library.

Comment: Yes, that kind of sharing is to a device and account. Your friend will need to revoke your old device and authorize the new one. Steam technology is too sophisticated to assume that copying a folder is enough to authorize a device.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since steam is proprietary software I don't think you will find definitive answer.

My guess is that steam recognize your computer based on your cofiguration and this configuration is saved somewhere on the cloud (same as microsoft oem licence). So my quess is that steam will recognize your computer even without config files.

Then I found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/4w7ew7/what_does_steam_use_to_identify_computers_for/) thread that says otherwise... (I think it's bullshit)

My recommendation for you is to make copy of your steam folder and steam registry keys. Make new installation and see if it works. If not rewrite steam with your backup. If even this didn't help, you need to login again.

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Steam doesn't store anything other than your local machine's unique ID number on your local machine. When your friend logged in, he added your machine's ID to the list of IDs authorised to use his games. When your machine identifies itself to Steam at login time, Steam server confirms whether this is still the case, and shows you the combined list of games.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you give me more details?
Which ID exactly? MAC? Serial Number? An encrypted key generated at the time of authorization saved somewhere on my drive?
I know how it works, but I need the actual details so I can copy it somehow

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think on Linux the randomly generated ID is in ~/.steam/steam.token. On the opaque mess that is Windows, I wouldn't want to even try to guess where it might be since there is no steam.token file. And that's assuming this is the only check. Valve actively want you to not be able to do what you are attempting here.